# Prove that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2$ is not rational

Tags: rational-numbers

How do I prove that the following is not rational?

$$x=\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2$$

To prove a simpler case like $\sqrt{2}=a/b$, I can raise both sides to the power of 2 and get $a^2=2b^2$, therefore both $a$ and $b$ must be even numbers which can't be true.

Comment: This is unreadable.  If you are asking about $\sqrt 2 +\sqrt[3] 2$ then that is irrational so you can't prove that it is rational.

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Comment: For algebraic numbers , the most straightford way to decide their rationality is to determine their minimal polynomial. If and only if its degree is $1$ , the given number is rational.

Comment: For the given $x$, the proof is not so easy as in the mentioned simpler example.

Comment: "therefore both a and b must be even numbers which can't be true." Why not? (I am asking the OP this)

Comment: Are you allowed to use the precalculus/school-algebra rational root theorem? If so, then a little algebra leads you to a 6th degree polynomial whose only possible rational roots are $\pm 1,$ $\pm 2,$ $\pm 4,$ each of which is is easily seen to not be a root of that 6th degree polynomial.

Comment: @AdamRubinson we could assume that a/b don't have any common factor, otherwise we would simplify it to a'/b' with common factors removed.

Comment: That’s right. You should have written those details in the question as it highlights where the contradiction arose in the proof if irrationality of $\sqrt{2}.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let
$$x=\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2$$
then
$$x-\sqrt 2 = \sqrt[3]2$$
$$\left(x-\sqrt 2 \right)^3=2$$
$$x^3-3x^2\left( \sqrt 2 \right)+3x(2)-2\left( \sqrt 2 \right)=2$$
$$\sqrt 2= \frac {x^3+6x-2}{3x^2+2}$$

$x$ cannot be rational because $\frac {x^3+6x-2}{3x^2+2}$ will then be rational and yet $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Comment: Straightforward and simple. Well done!